# Can I access the assignment of a function from inside that function?

Tags: r, rlang

I want to turn the assignment into a string and have it be one of the outputs of the function.

**Input:**

```
y <- f(x)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
"y"
```

I thought maybe `sys.call()` would help but it doesn't seem to include the assignment.

Comment: This question has been asked before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204937/how-do-i-access-the-name-of-the-variable-assigned-to-the-result-of-a-function-wi) but it didn't receive an answer there either.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I searched but didn't find that one. Feel free to close this question.

Comment: Well this is an interesting question that still hasn't been answered so I think it's worth keeping.

Comment: Would it be ok to change the function call to `f(y, x)` ?  In that case f <- `function(y, x) list(y = deparse(substitute(y)), x = x)` so to test it `f(zz, 3)`